# Padding on element disappears when using .append() after AJAX request gets the data

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, append

A div like this:

```
<div id="someid" class="someclass">
    <a href="#">content</a>
    <span class="btn1" title="Btn1">Btn1</span>
    <span class="btn2" title="Btn2">Btn2</span>
</div>
```

Both have padding applied to them in a separate CSS file. Displaying the data through PHP directly(without AJAX) the padding works however if I do the same, but use the AJAX connection and append the response, the padding on the span's disappear.

I'm not even sure if it's the padding because manually removing the padding it looks different than from what I get from the AJAX response.

I'm confused about what's happening here.

I'll try explaining via this "picture":

```
From PHP: | Content |Btn1|  |Btn2| |
From AJAX: | Content |Btn1||Btn2| |
```

The space between the buttons disappears for some reason.

Can it be that when loading the data through AJAX(no page refresh) it doesn't re-apply the CSS rules as compared to through PHP(with page refresh)?

PS: I stripped down all my code to bare essentials to make sure nothing in my AJAX settings was altering the response etc.

EDIT:

Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "data.php",
    data: {"data": requestObj},
    success: function(data) {
        $("#containerDiv").append(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you compare the resulting html page of both versions? Maybe the append is not correct and they are differnt. The CSS rules should work.

Comment: Please provide a jQuery.

Comment: @tea2code Just checked, yes they're the same, they even have the same rules. Used Chrome's inspector.

Comment: is this publicly available?

Comment: Have you used `.css` anywhere in your jQuery. That would add the styles to the style tag of the elements rather than the CSSOM meaning any new elements wouldnt automatically get those styles. Also it is worthwhile looking in the Chrome inspector at the computed styles of the elements in question to see if they differ

Comment: @DGS Even computed styles are the same for both. I do use .css in a few places, but they don't affect those elements or anything close(parents, children etc.) to them.